# Core Plot Graph Label steps

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot to draw graphs in my app.
I just encountered a problem:

- I have dates on the X-Axis and I use a custom labeling policy.
- If I only have a few records everything works fine
- If I have many records all the labels are near and not useful :-(

So the question is: How can I decide which values display and which not to always have 10 labels, separated one from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the number of points by the number of labels you want and round up. For example, if you have 25 data points and want roughly 10 labels, label every third data point. You'll end up with 9 evenly spaced labels.